# How to convert json to JSONP after it json load as a subscription in angular?

Tags: json, angular, kendo-ui, jsonp, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to make a call with jsonp but i have json data as a subscription
my service.ts file:-

```
  gridUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  getGrid() {
    return this.http.get<Grid>(this.gridUrl, httpOptions);

  }
```

and in my component.ts

```
  grid: Grid;
  grids: any;

  showGrid() {
    this.gridService.getGrid()
      .subscribe(
        gridData => this.grids = gridData 
      );
  }
```

That above code is working fine and gives me data in grids variable as a json

But I need to use that json data in below code .

```
private fetch(action: string = '', data?: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http
        .jsonp(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}`, 'callback')
        .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res));
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: json & jsonp response will be similar, later severs for cross domain req.

Comment: @supercool, I also need to send httpHeaders along with it, I am unable to do so. can you please tell me , how would i proceed ?

Comment: passing headers something like his `jsonp(url, {  params: params });` params is a object you can your header info & don;t forget to include `callback`.

Comment: @supercool I tried to do that, But I am unable to do that,
.jsonp(`http://myapi/list/packages/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}, 
{ params: 'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Accept':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': mysecretkey }`, 'callback')

Comment: @supercool, I am sorry to bother you , but I am not able to resolve or understand. 
private fetch(action: string = '', data?: any): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http
            .jsonp(`https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}`, 'callback')
            .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res));
    }, 
Its working fine but , I am another api which need to respond with header, How would I enter the header in there;
These are my value for header
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': mysecretkey

Comment: my apologies i forgot the basic one you cant add headers to `jsonp` @mainsh . you should enable end point to support full CORS and make a get call `(new RequestOptions({//add headers}))` which will work obvious

Comment: @supercool , I am on angular, so can you please tell me how do I code it?